# One to zero-or-one relationship with additional tables related only to zero-or-one table

Tags: sql-server, database, relational-database

So I have a User table that holds all user information within my application.  User's can have at most one profile, but not all users will have a profile (admin's for example).  Therefore, I made the relationship between these two tables one to zero-or-one.

[image]

This works just fine, but a Profile can have additional data that only relates to a Profile.  For example a link to various social media accounts a user may have.  These links are only ever shown when displaying a profile, so I went ahead and made the relationship from SocialMediaLink to Profile instead of the User table.  SocialMediaLinkType is just a lookup table for social media sites - "Twitter", "Facebook", etc.

[image]

Now my question stems from this second relationship. It seems odd to me to be referencing the UserId PK/FK column on the Profile table to the SocialMediaLink table rather than just referencing the UserId PK on the User table.  But at the same time, a SocialMediaLink doesn't exactly have a direct reference to the User because it is really a part of the profile.  A SocialMediaLink would only ever be shown when displaying the profile.  Also, there are at least 3 other tables of additional Profile data, so there would be

Am I over-complicating this?  Is it perfectly fine to have the User table just reference the SocialMediaLink and any other additional tables related to the Profile, even when some user records won't have those associated records (like in the case of an admin)?  Or is there added benefit to keeping the link on the Profile table, say for a cascade delete where deleting the profile deletes all the additional table data without having to touch the User table at all?

Also, for what it's worth I am using Entity Framework with this database in the application, but I am more interested in what actual relational database theory suggests versus how to get things working with EF.

Comment: UserID has no business being in the Profile table or SocialMediaLink table.  I would say add a nullable ProfileID foreign key to your User table.

Comment: Ill disagree with @Andrew.  1-1 relationship for user to profile is fine.  a 1-M relationship from profile to social media link is fine with userID being the FK between teh two and profile.pk being userId, same as user.id.  Now for a second, Forget application use.  Is it true that a socialMediaLink will only EVER be used when a user has a profile?  Since admins are the only users without profiles, could an admin have a socialmedia link?  I'd probably link to users in the first place to flatten the design.  What benefit does it have going though profile other than exclude admins..be flexible

Comment: I agree xQbert.  I would rather use the 1-0..1 instead of adding a Unique Key on the ProfileId FK on User to enforce uniqueness.  I see your point as well in being flexible.  As for the benefit, I guess there really isn't one besides excluding admins.

Comment: @ryanulit it's very confusing having so many fields called `id`. I suspect you have some redundancy in the design, and some unnecessary surrogate keys, but it's really hard to tell.

Comment: Here's a really good principle for field naming: if fields in different tables mean the same thing (for example one is a FK to t'other) then name them the same. If they mean different things, give them different names. For example User.Id I think should be named User.UserId (to show the FK to Profile); SocialMediaLink.Id should be named something other than Id.

Comment: My personal preference is to name the PK of a table as Id and use the full name when referenced as a FK. I like doing so to avoid the redundancy of typing User.UserId in SQL queries and EF code.  I can assure you there is no redundancy in the design, as each PK is it's own, except for the UserId PK on the profile table.  I understand and have used the field naming principle you mentioned before, but I just personally prefer the previous method.